# How to check if wifi is turned on/off in Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

The method DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled ins't available on Windows 10 any suggestion for check wifi is turned on/off?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a wireless connection, or whether the device has an (inter)network connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
using Windows.Devices.Radios;

public async Task<bool> IsWifiOn() 
{
                await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();

                var radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
                foreach (var radio in radios)
                {
                    if (radio.Kind == RadioKind.WiFi)
                    {
                        return  radio.State == RadioState.On;
                    }
                }
                return false;
}
```